# .htaccess url rewrite for sub-domain

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page in sub-domain `domain.com/blog/landing-page/`.

I want to open it as `domain.com/` so user will not know where my page is located.

I try below code but it doesn't work for me,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/landing-page[/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

I wrote this but it open domain/blog

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+blog/landing-page/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (?!^dirname/)^(.*)$ /blog/landing-page/$1 [L,NC]
```

How can i make it work ?

Comment: Your RegExp probably wants to be more like `^blog/landing-page/.*$` but this won't actually open that blog page, it'll redirect to the homepage - mod_rewrite isn't about tinkering with the address bar but actually directing requests.

Comment: possiple duplicate -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361419/hide-directory-name-from-url

Comment: could you not just set that folder as the root since you are doing so anyways? It would then have no need to show the directory.

Comment: @cclark413 how to set sub-domain as root?

Comment: @davidkonrad i tried that as well but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+blog/landing-page[/\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/landing-page/).*)$ /blog/landing-page/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} blog/landing-page/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* / [R=302,L]
```

Likely you were having an issue with you Regex, but it's good practive to confirm your `RewriteBase` as well. I left the `R=302` so that you can test everything out before you commit to the more permanent `R=301`

Comment: It open the page as it is `domain/blog/landing-page/`

Comment: @Shams, I modified the above code (I removed the leading forward slash from the `RewriteCond`). Let me know if that works.

Comment: i test it but it also doesn't work, I put another code in my question, it remove landing-page but still I need to remove blog

Comment: @Shams, I just created a test page on my local server `example.com/blog/landing-page/` and used the above .htaccess and everything worked. However, when the code was placed *below* my wordpress rewrite rules, it did not. So, do you have anything else in your .htaccess file, or is there anything else in the URL we don't know about (i.e. the above code assumes the last character of the URL is the `e` in `page` OR a `/`, but it will fail if there are url parameters). The point is, I think we are missing some info to help you out since I have confirmed that the above code works.

Comment: yes I have other code as well but I put that code at the top. How can I send you my .htaccess file so that you can have a look at it

Comment: @Shams, I think the best course of action is to establish that my code works for you. I would remove (well, comment out `#`) all of your other .htaccess code and copy/paste mine. Then from there we can start adding the other rules back in.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this. This will work.

http://chinjuharish.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/convert-incoming-url-from-upper-case-to-lower-case/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I dont want to convert uppercase to lower, please read my question

Comment: Ok Shams. Sory. I wil check it